# The flashlight disappears, but doesn't appear back

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to add a flashlight to my game. When I press the button to make it disappear, it disappears, but when I press the button to try to make it appear again it doesn't. I've been trying to find the solution for the past hour and a half and looked into the docs too but I didn't find anything.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class flashlight : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script is being deactivated along with the `gameObject` so it isn't listening for `Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha2)`.

To get round this create an empty GameObject to hold the script and make the light a child of said GameObject, then when you deactivate the light the script is still active and listening for the `Input`.

Update the script like this to assign the light child

```
public class flashlight : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject light;//Assign this is the inspector

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            light.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            light.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved me a lot of time.